# WordPress Post Status Transitions and get_post_meta

Tags: wordpress

When I try to use get_post_meta in a function that is called using the Post Status Transition add_action hook, it doesn't work.

If I call the same function directly from somewhere else, it works fine.

What's going on?

```
/* notification */

function new_notification($post){

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta_key',true);

    return $meta; // returns str if function run directly, returns empty (false) with hook

}

add_action('auto-draft_to_draft', 'new_notification');
add_action('new_to_draft', 'new_notification');
```

Comment: Does it happen with the same post ID?

Comment: Yes, and I've echoed different items from the post object to test that the post ID is accurately being sent.

Comment: You can debug the `get_post_meta` function itself to see what's happening inside.

Comment: Post meta data is not (yet) stored in the DB for new or auto-draft posts. When transitioning to draft status, the metadata will get stored but only _after_ your notification function ran.